# C# Binding data to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

**SOLVED: My frontcolor of the combobox was set to White, hence I didn't see them.**

I know this has been asked alot, I've been searching on Google but haven't found a solution to my problem. Nothing seems to work.

I want to bind data to my combobox (which comes from a database) but it's always blank. But when I bind the same data to a list, data appears..

XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboCPType" Style="{StaticResource comboboxenright}" ItemsSource="{Binding CPTypeList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="SelectedPerson.JobRole.ID"/>
```

viewmodel

```
private ObservableCollection<ContactPersonType> _CPTypeList;
    public ObservableCollection<ContactPersonType> CPTypeList
    {
        get
        {
            return _CPTypeList;
        }
        set
        {
            _CPTypeList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CPTypeList");
        }
    }
```

model

```
private String _Name;
    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
        }
    }
public static ObservableCollection<ContactPersonType> GetTypes()
    {
        ObservableCollection<ContactPersonType> lijst = new ObservableCollection<ContactPersonType>();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM ContactpersoonType";
        DbDataReader reader = Database.GetData(sql);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ContactPersonType cType = new ContactPersonType();
            cType.Id = reader["ID"].ToString();
            cType.Name = reader["Naam"].ToString();
            lijst.Add(cType);
        }
        return lijst;
    }
```

Comment: Have you include `DisplayMember = "ColumnNameHereToDisplay"`? By the way is this winform or WPF?

Comment: I have DisplayMemberPath="" , DisplayMember="" doesn't exist

Comment: I guess this is not winform but WPF, right? Try this link [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301678/Step-by-Step-WPF-Data-Binding-with-Comboboxes)

Comment: Yes sorry, should have mentioned that. It's WPF. I'm not allowed to touch the code behind. It's MVVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you must have a class with a property named `Name`, but you don't show your code or what/where/how you actually initialize `CPTypeList`.

Have a look at this article I've wrote:
[Understanding SelectedValue, SelectedValuePath, SelectedItem & DisplayMemberPath + Demo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671544/Understanding-SelectedValue-SelectedValuePath-Sele).
Hopefully it'll clear some things for you :)

Also, have a look at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20416222/1698987) to make sure you have the datacontext set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've added the model code. (properties etc)

Comment: Solved the problem, the frontcolor of the combobox was white, hence I didn't see the items....